# BigQuery query response 'jobComplete': False

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I have the following function :

```
def query_big_query(query_data, project_id):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials_bq.json')
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
    try:
        query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
        query_response = query_request.query(projectId=project_id, body=query_data).execute()
        return query_response
    except HttpError as error:
        print ('Error :{}'.format(error.content))
        raise error
```

However some of queries don't return the data, bacause the query takes a bit of time, and return the following string :

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'jobComplete': False, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'od', u'jobId': u'job_5wAuC'}}
```

How can I wait until the job is completed (True)? Or should I request the results as a different call?

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying a larger *timeoutMs* inside *body*, like:

`query_response = query_request.query(projectId=project_id, body={'query': your_query, 'timeoutMs': 180000}).execute()`

By default, *timeoutMs* is 10000, which is 10 seconds.

Reference: [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response = bigquery_service.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=my_project_id, jobId=my_job_id).execute()
while not response['jobComplete']:
    print "waiting for response..."
    time.sleep(1)
    response = bigquery_service.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=my_project_id, jobId=my_job_id).execute()
return response
```